# How to take snapshot of image element with UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I need to take a snapshot of a certain element inside a UIWebView, that is an image, while the UIWebView is hidden.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!